# Delay in systemNavigationBarColor and statusBarColor in theme change - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the application's theme but there is a delay in the systemNavigationBarColor and statusBarColor.

Even in the release version of the application this happens. Added a short code with the theme change.

Is there any way to change them with the theme without it causing the delay?

[image]

```
  void changeTheme(ThemeMode themeMode) {
    setState(() {
      _themeMode = themeMode;
    });

    bool isDark = themeMode.name == 'dark';

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarIconBrightness: isDark ? Brightness.light : Brightness.dark,
      statusBarColor: isDark ? Color(0xff1a1a1a) : Colors.white,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness:
          isDark ? Brightness.light : Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarColor: isDark ? Color(0xff1a1a1a) : Colors.white,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor:
          isDark ? Color(0xff1a1a1a) : Colors.white,
    ));
  }

******************


  Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () =>
                        MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.light),
                    child: Text('Light')),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () =>
                        MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.dark),
                    child: Text('Dark')),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Can you use Debug Mode for testing this code?

Comment: You can use release mode app for better testing..

Comment: But I use the 2
ways